# Extraer la cadena de certificacion en c#

Tags: c#

Quisiera tener acceso a la cadena de certificación de un certificado instalado en el almacén de certificados de windows, actualmente obtengo esta cadena pero a partir de un archivo pfx con su clave, pero ahora cambiaron la forma y quieren que se extraiga de un certificado instalado.
el código actual que si me funciona es el sgt:

```
string certPath = "nombre del cert";
string certPass = "clave";
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();

collection.Import(certPath, certPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

int ncontador = 0;
foreach (X509Certificate2 certR in collection ) 
{

}
```

Alguien me puede apoyar, para que en vez de extraerlo  a partir de un fichero , extraerlo de un certificado instalado (ojo quiero tener acceso a la cadena de certificacion desde el certificado raiz)

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente podes acceder al almacén de certificados que están instalados en windows.

El siguiente código primero muestra un listado de certificados instalados y luego muestra la información de uno en particular.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ListadoCertificadosLocales
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MostrarListadoCertificados();

            Console.WriteLine("----------------------");

            MostrarInfoCertificado("Root", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fuente: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store(v=vs.110).aspx
        /// </summary>
        private static void MostrarListadoCertificados()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nExists Certs Name and Location");
            Console.WriteLine("------ ----- -------------------------");

            foreach (StoreLocation storeLocation in (StoreLocation[])
                Enum.GetValues(typeof(StoreLocation)))
            {
                foreach (StoreName storeName in (StoreName[])
                    Enum.GetValues(typeof(StoreName)))
                {
                    X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);

                    try
                    {
                        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

                        Console.WriteLine("Yes    {0,4}  {1}, {2}",
                            store.Certificates.Count, store.Name, store.Location);
                    }
                    catch (CryptographicException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No           {0}, {1}",
                            store.Name, store.Location);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Muestra por consola la informacion para un almacen
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nombreAlmacen">Nombre del almacen que se quiere acceder</param>
        /// <param name="ubicacion">Especifica la ubicación del almacén de certificados X.509.</param>
        private static void MostrarInfoCertificado(string nombreAlmacen, StoreLocation ubicacion)
        {
            try
            {
                X509Store almacen = new X509Store(nombreAlmacen, ubicacion);
                almacen.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection storecollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)almacen.Certificates;
                Console.WriteLine("Nombre almacen: {0}", almacen.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Ubicacion almacen: {0}", almacen.Location);
                foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in storecollection)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nombre certificado: {0}", x509.Subject);
                }
            }
            catch (CryptographicException cryexc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: MostrarInfoCertificado:{0}", cryexc.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Estimado gracias por tu respuesta. el parametro nombreCert  de la funcion MostrarInfoCertificado  cual debe ser el valor:  el CN? o en que formato debo enviarlo. Reitero mi agradecimiento por tu respuesta

Comment: Deseariá acceder a la ruta de certificación de un certificado selecionado, se puede acceder a ello con tu código. Gracias

Comment: Hice una corrección  al código, debía ser el nombre del almacén.

Te dejo un link que indica como poder ver los certificados:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms788967(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Claro estimado, ahora como podria acceder a la ruta de certificacion de un certificado específico. Como puse en el código inicial si fuera con un certificado contenido en un archivo si se puede, pero escojerlo del almacen de certificados  la verdad no se como obtenerlo. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una solución al menos para lo que necesito:

```
var miCert = new X509Certificate2(pathToCert, password);

X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
chain.Build(miCert);
for (int i = 0; i < chain.ChainElements.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(chain.ChainElements[i].Certificate.Issuer);
}
```

La primera linea la editaría para que tenga el objeto *(desde el almacén de certificados)*.